# Analytic solution to the integral of the Butterworth bandpass frequency response

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm writing a physics simulation code, one portion of which involves the integration of the frequency response of an arbitrary [$N^{th}$-order Butterworth bandpass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter). That is, I wish to solve:

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\bigg(\frac{\big(\frac{f}{f_0} - \frac{f_0}{f}\big)^2}{W^2}\bigg)^N}}\; df$$

...where $f,f_0$, and $W$ are arbitrary real-valued constants, and $N$ is some positive nonzero integer ([see also](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68277/butterworth-band-pass-filter-transfer-function)).

---

It occurs to me that I could greatly simplify (and speed up) this portion of the code by instead finding an analytic solution (or a symbolic approximation). I've tried working this out myself, with no success, and have also tried passing this to Mathematica, `SymPy`, and various integral solvers, to no avail. Encouragingly, `SymPy`'s Risch-based solver (while unable to return a solution) claims that the integral is *not* nonelementary.

**Is there an analytic solution to this integral? If not, is there a relatively straight-forward symbolic approximation?**